# sorting an array into two separate arrays of animal names, softAnimals and notSoftAnimals

Tags: javascript, arrays

struggling with how to write a function that sorts this array properly into two separate arrays. I can't figure out where to go from here, I know i need to probably use the sort method but I don't know how to write it properly, I've only been working with JS for a couple weeks.

```
    let mixedUpAnimals = [
     {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
     {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
     {name: 'bear', soft: true},
     {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
     {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
     {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
     {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
     ]
     for(var i = 0; i < mixedUpAnimals.length; i++){
     if (mixedUpAnimals[i].soft === true);
```

Comment: What you are describing is filtering, not sorting. Sorting refers to the ordering of a list by a particular criteria.

Answer (score 1):

First, you can [`sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) and then [`filter`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) the elements (separately just for understanding the sort and filter methods):

```js
let mixedUpAnimals = [
     {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
     {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
     {name: 'bear', soft: true},
     {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
     {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
     {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
     {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
     ]

 mixedUpAnimals.sort(function(a , b) {
    return a.name > b.name;
});

var softAnimals = mixedUpAnimals.filter(function (el) {
  return el.soft });


var notSoftAnimals = mixedUpAnimals.filter(function (el) {
  return !el.soft });
  

console.log( softAnimals);
console.log( notSoftAnimals);
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do the separation in a single iteration as well, once you sorted.

```js
let mixedUpAnimals = [
     {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
     {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
     {name: 'bear', soft: true},
     {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
     {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
     {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
     {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
  ],
  sortCb = (x, y)=> x.name.localeCompare(y.name),
  separate = A => A.reduce((a, e) => ((e.soft && a.s || a.ns).push(e), a), {s: [], ns: []}),
  {s, ns} = separate(mixedUpAnimals.sort(sortCb));
  
  console.log('Soft: ', s);
  console.log('Non soft: ', ns);
```

Also you can avoid sort at the beginning, find the proper index in child array and place the item in child array at appropriate index, even it is a searching multiple time but remember we are searching in smaller arrays, so the entire operation, (including sort and separate) will have much less complexity and faster.  here is the version:

```js
let mixedUpAnimals = [
     {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
     {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
     {name: 'bear', soft: true},
     {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
     {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
     {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
     {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
  ],
  separate = A => A.reduce((a, e) => {
    let t = (e.soft && a.s || a.ns),
        idx = t.findIndex(v=> v.name.localeCompare(e.name) > 0);
    t.splice(idx < 0 ? t.length : idx, 0 , e);
    return a;
  }, {s: [], ns: []}),
  {s, ns} = separate(mixedUpAnimals);
  
    
console.log('Soft: ', s);
console.log('Non soft: ', ns);
```

Comment: Yes, I have reverted the last edit. Please don't edit the meaning of the code. in `,` is there that meants continuation of declaration.

Comment: @AluanHaddad no it will. but it will mutate the source array. in order to avoid that we can `slice` before but that's optional

Answer (score 0):

```
const soft = mixedUpAnimals.filter(animal => animal.soft);
const notSoft = mixedUpAnimals.filter(animal => !animal.soft);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
 let mixedUpAnimals = [
   {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
   {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
   {name: 'bear', soft: true},
   {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
   {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
   {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
   {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
]

let softAnimals = [];
let notSoftAnimals =[];

mixedUpAnimals.map((item) => { 
  item.soft ? softAnimals.push(item) : notSoftAnimals.push(item)
});

function sortArrayOfObject(items){
  return items.sort((a, b)=> {
    var nameA = a.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    var nameB = b.name.toUpperCase(); // ignore upper and lowercase
    if (nameA < nameB) return -1;
    if (nameA > nameB) return 1;
    return 0;
  });
}

console.log(sortArrayOfObject(softAnimals))
console.log(sortArrayOfObject(notSoftAnimals))
```

Answer (score -1):

You can use the [sort()](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_sort.asp) method

```js
const mixedUpAnimals = [
  {name: 'chinchilla', soft: true},
  {name: 'armadillo', soft: false},
  {name: 'bear', soft: true},
  {name: 'porcupine', soft: false},
  {name: 'hedgehog', soft: false},
  {name: 'honey badger', soft: false},
  {name: 'mouse', soft: true}
];

const sortedAnimals = mixedUpAnimals.sort((a, b) => (a.soft < b.soft) ? 1 : -1);

console.log(sortedAnimals);
```

This way the animals with `soft: true` will be at top. If you need to reverse the order, simply reverse the `<` sign.